# View specific fields as ndarray with numpy >= 1.13

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Data is in a structured array:

```
import numpy as np
dtype = [(field, float) for field in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'prop1', 'prop2']]
data = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10), (11,12,13,14,15)], dtype=dtype)
```

For some operations, the positions are accessed as a single nx3 array, for example:

```
positions = data[['x', 'y', 'z']].view(dtype=float).reshape(-1, 3)
ranges = np.sqrt(np.sum(positions**2, 1))
```

Since numpy 1.12, the following warning is emitted:

> FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you may be viewing or writing to an array returned by selecting multiple fields in a
>   structured array.
>
> This code may break in numpy 1.13 because this will return a view instead of a copy -- see release notes for details.

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#multiple-field-manipulation-of-structured-arrays) is the corresponding entry in the release notes:

> Indexing a structured array with multiple fields (eg, `arr[['f1', 'f3']]`) will return a view into the original array in 1.13, instead of a copy. Note the returned view will have extra padding bytes corresponding to intervening fields in the original array, unlike the copy in 1.12, which will affect code such as `arr[['f1', 'f3']].view(newdtype)`.

How to port this code to numpy >=1.13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking on numpy 1.13 the announced change doesn't appear to have happened yet. So let's simulate the future:

The future behavior will presumably be not to copy the data but to create a dtype that has only the fields you want, but the `itemsize` of the original dtype. So there will be gaps in each element, parts of memory that are not used.

```
xyz_tp = xyz_tp = np.dtype({'names': list('xyz'),
                            'formats': tuple(data.dtype.fields[f][0] for f in 'xyz'),
                            'offsets': tuple(data.dtype.fields[f][1] for f in 'xyz'), 
                            'itemsize': data.dtype.itemsize})

xyz = data.view(xyz_tp)
xyz
# array([(  1.,   2.,   3.), (  6.,   7.,   8.), ( 11.,  12.,  13.)],
#       dtype={'names':['x','y','z'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[0,8,16], 'itemsize':40})
```

The not used memory locations and their content are ignored but still there, so if you view with a builtin dtype they'll reappear.

```
xyz.view(float)
# array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
#         12.,  13.,  14.,  15.])
# Ouch!
```

The general fix would be to cast to a contiguous (no gaps) dtype with the same fields. This will force a copy

```
xyz_cont_tp = np.dtype({'names': list('xyz'), 'formats': 3*('<f8',)})
xyz.astype(xyz_cont_tp).view(float).reshape(-1, 3)
# array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
#        [  6.,   7.,   8.],
#        [ 11.,  12.,  13.]])
```

In the special case of your selected fields being contiguous and of same type you can also do:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(data.view(float), shape=(3,3), strides=data.strides + (8,))
# array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
#        [  6.,   7.,   8.],
#        [ 11.,  12.,  13.]])
```

This method does not copy data but creates a genuine view.

Answer (score 0):

Other way for several adjacent float fields. Here for 3 fields starting from 'x' we obtain same result with:

`np.ndarray((len(data),3), float, data, offset= data.dtype.fields['x'][1], strides= (data.strides[0], np.dtype(float).itemsize))`